# Button to add my facebook-app to favorites?

Tags: javascript, facebook, button, sdk, favorites

Is there a possibility to add an app to the favorites menu(under users avatar) of the user with js sdk button or dialog?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no API which allows apps to add themselves to the favourites section of a user's bookmarks. I believe this is intentional, as to allow apps to do this would make the list less authentic.